# Anybody knows PayPal API (C#) for updating order status and adding tracking number?

Tags: c#, paypal

I want to update Paypal Order status and add tracking number using API.

but I can not find API documents or example for that.

anybody knows, please advice me~

Thank you!

**API for this :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no API for this unfortunately.

Comment: Has there been any updates on API for Adding Tracking Info in Paypal?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no

Comment: Hey Robert, are you working with PayPal - any update on this or must we screen scrape etc? If we add tracking info via eBay API does it link it with PayPal account?? Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Is this still true?

Comment: No longer true , added link in answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a new REST-based API now: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/